# Version control of a web server config files

Tags: php, apache, version-control, freebsd

Between me and a Network Architect we manage a bunch of Web Servers (FreeBSD). He's responsible for all server/network related stuff (IPs, Firewalls, users/groups, etc.) and I'm responsible for all web-related stuff (Apache, PHP, MySQL). Sometimes the responsibilities overlap.

It happend few times that some changes were made to the config files which more or less affected the server and we were not able to figure out which of us made the changes and why.

I - being a Web Developer - think it'd be a good practice to put the files under version control (we currently use Subversion), so that whenever we change anything we have to commit an comment the changes. It'll solve all the problems with wondering who did what and why.

The particular config files I was thinking of were:

- firewall config
- apache config (with extras)
- php config (php.ini)
- MySQL config (my.conf)

I already know, that the idea version control of server config files is sound based on [other question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243174/should-server-database-config-files-including-passwords-be-stored-in-source-con). My only worry is how to do it properly on the Web Server side since the files are in different locations. Putting the whole `/usr/local/etc` under version control seems pointless as it contains not just the config files.

I was wondering whether not to create a new folder, say `/config` which would be under version control and would contain all the config files we need and then replace the original ones with symlinks to ones in the `/config` folder. E.g.:

```
/usr/local/etc/apache22/httpd.conf -> /config/apache22/httpd.conf
```

So the question is: **Is this a good idea and if not, what is a better solution?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use GIT then puitting the whole  `/usr/local/etc` under version control is not pointless at all.

- you can only track a handfull of files if you so chose
- the working directory with all config files tracked is hardly bigger in size

Just install git, then go to `/usr/local/etc` and write `git init`. This will create the .git folder in your current location (basically making this folder a repository).

Then add the config files you want to track:
 `git add firewall/firewall_config.conf apache2/httpd.conf` etc
and commit: `git commit -m "Initial Configuration"`

Your config files are now being tracked.

Comment: You actually might be right. I am moving to git, but coming from SVN I have an image of each subfolder containing an .svn folder and TortoiseSVN reporting a whole bunch of unversioned files. This might be the way to go. Thanks DerShodan.

Comment: But what if config files are in different locations? E.g. firewall config is located in /etc. I would like to avoid having multiple git checkouts.

Comment: +1 for the mention of a DVCS. One. small. folder. one place. (and a decent answer too)

Comment: About mutliple config files in multiple locations: As long as you are in /etc you can just add the files you need to the repository. Other option is, as you suggested yourself, just move configs to track in one folder and replace original configs with symlinks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are versioning sensitive configuration files, I would recommend setting up  an internal git server like gitlab.  Create a git repository for each server, or server template/image/etc.  Go to the / directory and 'git init'.

You can be selective about what you put under version  control by only using 'git add /path/to/file for the files that you will be customizing.

Then, 'git -m 'commit comment' and 'git push -u origin master'.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at any of the management tools made to do just this sort of thing?  I recommend Puppet or Chef, having used them in previous jobs to do this sort of thing.

Comment: how can puppet / chef be helpful here? can you elaborate the idea?