# Flask - Avoid putting full username and password in config

Tags: python, shell, flask, debian

I am doing automatic deployments from GIT and I wanted to avoid putting my full username and password within the config.py like this:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "postgresql://yourusername:yourpassword@localhost/yournewdb"
```

I wondered how people would approach this?

James

Comment: More generic overview of the problem is available at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243174/should-server-database-config-files-including-passwords-be-stored-in-source-co/4319411#4319411

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always stick them inside environment variables, then read them from your code. That way your commits would never push the creds up to source control. Not ideal, but it'd do the job.

Answer (score 1):

If *config.py* does not change often you could add it to *.gitignore* and manually upload it to the production server the first time or when it changes.

A similar option is to read *SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI* from any place that is not committed into git. For example, environment variables (like @Polynomial suggests) or an alternative configuration file.