# How do I handle a secret API Key when I push to GitHub so that my project is still functional when the repo is cloned?

Tags: git, api-key, secret-key

I have a simple project that makes HTTP requests to an API endpoint and uses an API Key that I want to keep secret. Initially I put the key in its own file, imported the key into the file that uses it, and added the key file to the .gitignore. The problem is that this approach won't work if someone clones the GitHub repository.

So my question is - how can I keep my API key secret, but have my project still be functional if someone clones the repo?

Any feedback greatly appreciated.

Comment: offer a helpful error message in the case it's undefined? If it needs something you're not providing to work, i don't see how it can work without providing that something...

Comment: I'd think you'd probably want to have a local dev environment where authentication is not required or you have some mock local api.

Comment: Impossible to keep the API key safe if you allow other people to use the app and the app somehow has access to the key as they could modify the repo code to log the API key

Comment: @dandavis thanks for your feedback! I agree with you, I just wasn't sure if there was a solution that could avoid publicly posting the key on github.

Comment: @matthew257 good point. Thanks!

Comment: Is the repo public or for internal 'trusted' devs?

Comment: It's a public repo. This is for a coding assignment as part of a job application, and I wanted to show that I'm concerned with keeping the API key secret.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should server/database config files, including passwords, be stored in source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243174/should-server-database-config-files-including-passwords-be-stored-in-source-co)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+store+application+password

Answer (score 5):

Most importantly, you do not add it, ever. If you added it, committed it, and then removed it, it is still possible to recover it as a stranger with access to your repo by checking out the old commit.

With that out of the way, what you can do:

- Prominently tell the user that they need to get and set up their own API key - and maybe even how to do so.
- Add a check at the start of your software, that provides a helpful error message if the API key is missing, and otherwise starts your actual program
- Add a dummy file to show how it should be set up. I did that for my telegram chatbot: never commit `secret.config`, but commit `sample_secret.config` so that anybody who forks your repository can see what syntax he would need to use. `sample_secret.config` is never used by the software, and instead of the API key contains a key like `this-is-4-dummy-API-key-3232` or whatever makes sense.
- Create a second API key which works but which can be abused by the public without any issues. Set everything up so that it works with either API key, and only commit the second one.

Comment: In this case the app wouldn't be functional as per the question

Comment: It's as functional as it should get when the repository is public. Anything more would be a question of "How do I keep my password secret while giving my password to strangers?" unless I misunderstand something

Comment: I don't disagree but your answer doesn't answer the question asked as the app, without the API key, physically cannot be functional

Comment: @matthew257 I see what you mean and added another idea. If you have more suggestions, I encourage you to add them in another answer :)

Comment: `sample_secret.config` or `secret.config.sample` would probably be more useful names.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine two cases, either you only use this code yourself on a limited set of computers or you want to publish a compiled version of the program that people can use.

If you only use it on a limited number of computers then you should probably "Install" the secret on those computers.  There are a few places they could be safely stored and tied to your credentials/login without being public (For instance, an encrypted directory, or just a private directory if you trust the computer/os to be secure)  Windows has a "Credential Manager" encrypted and tied to the user that you can access only if you are running as that user (It uses it to store web passwords and such)

If you want to publish the compiled app--well then your current solution isn't terribly good since you could just decompile the app and retrieve the secret.  Better to have a "key" download that stores the secret attached to their credentials as above.

Answer (score 0):

You should never commit API key to a GitHub repository. If you have committed it, you can remove it but then, it is still possible to recover it once someone checks the commit history. You should check how to remove sensitive data [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository).

So here's how to treat your API keys:

- You could tell the user/visitor of the repository to get his own API key. You could put some description on what files to edit and how to use on your readme.
- You could add a dummy file to show how to set it. You should not commit .env or secret.config but you should commit .env.sample or secret_sample.config as the case may be. Instead of the real API key, you could use something like "Your_API_Key" in the sample file so one reading would know what to do.

However, if you are running some GitHub actions to build the project, the action would surely fail as it can't fetch the API key. Here is what I do:

- Add the API key to the secrets of the repository. Every repository has secrets which are treated as an environment variable by Github actions even though they are not available at runtime.
- After adding the key to secrets, you should edit the part of the code where you used the API key to call the key from the environment. Assume I added and saved the API key as api_key in the GitHub secrets, here is how I would call it in dart:

```
import 'dart:io' show Platform;

String apiKey = Platform.environment['api_key'];
```

You should handle it like you are reading an environment variable in any programming language of choice.

- The api_key added to the GitHub secrets is not available to anyone.
  Only contributors to the repo have access and can check the secrets
  hence the key remains hidden to others but available to the
  owners/contributors of the repository.