# Is it safe to store login credentials in a #if DEBUG block?

Tags: c#, security, compilation

We are developing a program that contains a login mechanism. For convenience, user credentials are automatically entered when using a debug build.

```
#if DEBUG
  UsernameTextBox.Text = "someName";
  PasswordBox.Password = "somePassword";
```

As I understand, this would not be compiled in a release build and is safe to leave in the code (as long as users only get the release build). Is this true?

Comment: No, because then it will get committed to your repository.

Comment: I can confirm that this is not compiled, but it is not the safest way to do it, since a leak of the code can cause troubles. Keep in mind that, despite this won't be included in the code, .NET can be very easily decompiled, so if you are really concerned about the code itself, you should use a .NET code protector

Comment: Yes. Unless someone defines DEBUG in the 'Release'-build. (evil!) If this is allowed to use in your source-repo is another discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely not!

First, take a look at this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/191590/why-is-storing-passwords-in-version-control-a-bad-idea

Workarounds to this: [How do you avoid storing passwords in version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436328/how-do-you-avoid-storing-passwords-in-version-control)

If your question is wether or not it can be retrieved from the executable or the dll, the answer is no.

> When the C# compiler encounters an #if directive, followed eventually by an #endif directive, **it compiles the code** between the directives only if the specified symbol is defined. Unlike C and C++, you cannot assign a numeric value to a symbol. The #if statement in C# is Boolean and only tests whether the symbol has been defined or not.

The code is not even compiled, so not included in the executable.